# When concatenating two sequences, can evaluations of two input sequences be in parallel with each other?

Tags: programming-languages, parallel-computing

In *Practical Foundation of Programming Languages* by Harper (www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/pfpl/2nded.pdf),

> **37.3 Multiple Fork-Join**
>
> So far we have conﬁned attention to binary fork/join parallelism induced by the parallel
>   let construct. A generalizaton, called data parallelism, allows the simultaneous creation
>   of any number of tasks that compute on the components of a data structure.

There are two expressions:

```
seq(e_0 , . . . ,e_{n−1} )     sequence
...
cat(e_1 ; e_2 )     concatenate
```

In the cost dynamics,

[image]
[image]

- (37.9a) indicate that evaluation of a `seq` expression (forming a sequence from the n elements `e_i`'s) can be parallelized betwen the n elements.
- (37.9f) , evaluation of a `cat` expression (concatenate two sequences `e_1` and `e_2`)  first evaluates `e_1` and `e_2` to two sequences, and then consolidate their elements into one result sequence. Why are evaluations of `e_1` and `e_2` to two sequences not in parallel with each other?

Thanks.

Comment: Reading the description it looks like it is modeling multiple fork and join. Hence `seq` is forking multiple tasks and `cat` acts as joining all those. Hence tasks in the first `seq` would all have to be completed before the tasks in second `seq` would be performed. Thus they cannot be in parallel.